# C++ std::allocator::allocate() giving me a bad pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm recreating a linked list in C++ and am getting a bad pointer while overloading the += operator. I imagine that I'm just using the allocator in the wrong way, but I could be wrong.

Here is the context:

```
void MyLinkedList::operator+=( const std::string& s )
{
    allocator<Node> a;
    Node* n = a.allocate(1);

    Node node(s);
    (*n) = node;
    if ( first == NULL )
        first = n;
    else
    {
        (*current).SetNext(n);
        current = n;
    }
}
```

where `first` and `current` are of type `Node*`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) allocates raw unconstructed storage. To use the storage, you must use `.construct()`.

```
a.construct(n, /* initializer */);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I am having trouble when setting the old pointer to the `Node* next` in the `Node` pointed at by `current`. It is telling me there's an Access Violation in that writing location. I've Googled a little bit and it seems like I might have made my `Node`s in Read-Only memory. Did I, and if so, how do I put it in writable memory?